# Use SailsJS and socket io to keep all open copies of my website live as data change

Tags: socket.io, sails.js

Lets say I'm building yelp.

I need all my users who have the website open to have the same data at any given time. If a user like a place then that change must happen on all the pages.

I know this must be easy. But I need some guidance with this. Please comment it dumb proof :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the server and browser connected over websockets.  This code is cut out of working code and simplified, but not tested. It should be enough to get you started if you have a simple api already working. Sails 0.10.5

#### Browser

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  io.socket.get('/computer');
  io.socket.on('computer', function(updates){
    console.log("Got an update event");
  }
});
```

#### Server

```
// Add to controller
  index: function (req, res) {
    Computer.find({},function(err, computers){
      if(req.isSocket){
        console.log("websocket connected");
        Computer.subscribe(req.socket,computers);
      }
      return res.json(
        computers
      );
    });
  },

  // Add to model
  afterUpdate: function(computer, cb){
    console.log("Someone updated a model. Publishing update to ws subscribers");
      Computer.publishUpdate(computer.id, [computer]);
    cb();
  },
```

For more information, see the sails documentation http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/websockets/resourceful-pubsub
http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/websockets/sails.io.js

Comment: So, Back to yelp instance. People comment, review, upload photos .. So do I have to subscribe to all those controllers just as above as soon as a client connect to my web site ?

Comment: Anything just yet ? Thank you

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.

What you subscribe to is dependent on what data you return. Assuming something like yelp, a user might bring up a location. When a user brings up a location, you can subscribe them to that particular location.

In the controller index function, there's a call to Computer.subscribe. That would be Location.subscribe and would get a single location.  I don't know what happens with nested resource updating, though.

Comment: Allright. So it is not a global subscribe thing. Where every change will be handled from one place. Alright. I think I'm on the right path